# It restart sprint boot application when start job on Spring batch 4.1

Tags: spring-batch

I'm start a spring boot application with spring batch,but the spring boot application always restart when start spring batch job.

spring boot 2.1.3
spring batch 4.1.1

```java
    @Bean
    public FlatFileItemWriter<Person> writer(){

        return new FlatFileItemWriterBuilder<Person>()
                .name("personItemWriter")
                .resource(new ClassPathResource("result-data.csv"))
                .delimited()
                .delimiter(",")
                .names(new String[]{"firstName", "lastName"})
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Job importUserJob(JobCompletionNotificationListener listener, @Qualifier("step1") Step step1) {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("importUserJob")
                .listener(listener)
                .flow(step1)
                .end()
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step step1(PersonItemProcessor processor, FlatFileItemWriter<Person> writer){

        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
                .<Person, Person>chunk(10)
                .reader(reader())
                .processor(processor1())
                .writer(writer)
                .allowStartIfComplete(true)
                .build();

    }
```

I expect spring boot application don't restart

Answer (score 0):

You can specifie this properties to not start the batch automatically at spring boot launch.

spring.batch.job.enabled=false

Comment: But I start job, the spring boot application still restart